# XSLT identity transform with additional header row copy and manipulation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been struggling with this problem and I am hoping you could help.  I tried it a number of ways myself and searched this site and others but could not find quite the right answer.  Thanks very much in advance.

I want to take an input XML document and output a similar copy with these changes:

1. A new header record in the same format as the sibling records inserted every time the value of a certain element of the siblings changes.  The header element will be a copy of the first sibling with some slight changes.
2. All of the regular, non-header records will have some values changed too.

I tried using the http://exslt.org/common node-set function as well as node sets as variables in xslt 2.0 but got lost.

Sample input, the rows are assumed to be sorted by type.

```
<fruits>
    <fruit>

        <row>1</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Gala </name>
        <color> Red </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>

        <row>2</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Fuji </name>
        <color> Red </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>

        <row>3</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Golden Delcious </name>
        <color> Yellow </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>

        <row>4</row>
        <type> Orange </type>
        <name> Clementine </name>
        <color> Orange </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <row>5</row>
        <type> Orange </type>
        <name> Sunburst </name>
        <color> Orange </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>
</fruits>
```

This is the sample output.  For each set of rows by type, add a header row above that type row in the same format.  The name and color should be nulled out in the header row and the row value should have an 'H' prepended to it, otherwise it is the same as the next regular row.  In the following regular rows of the same type, the country should be nulled out.

```
<fruits>
    <fruit>

        <row>H1</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> </name>
        <color> </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>

        <row>1</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Gala </name>
        <color> Red </color>
        <country> </country>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>

        <row>2</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Fuji </name>
        <color> Red </color>
        <country> </country>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>

        <row>3</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Golden Delcious </name>
        <color> Yellow </color>
        <country> </country>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>

        <row>H4</row>
        <type> Orange </type>
        <name> </name>
        <color> </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>

        <row>4</row>
        <type> Orange </type>
        <name> Clementine </name>
        <color> Orange </color>
        <country> </country>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <row>5</row>
        <type> Orange </type>
        <name> Sunburst </name>
        <color> Orange </color>
        <country> </country>
    </fruit>
</fruits>
```

Here is a part of the XSLT that I tried.  I did an identity transform first, and was successful in creating an additional header row every time the type changes.  However I don't know how to manipulate the header or regular rows to get the desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- create the extra header row every time the type changes -->
    <xsl:template match="fruit">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="type != preceding-sibling::*[1]/type">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- create the header row for the first row where preceding sibling is null -->
            <xsl:when test="row = 1">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Solutions in xslt 1.0 would be preferred but 2.0 would be fine too.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'll edit the answer accordingly but, do you mean something like this?

(Here I'm only transforming "row" node for example propourses)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:copy>H<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- create the extra header row every time the type changes -->
    <xsl:template match="fruit">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="type != preceding-sibling::*[1]/type">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- create the header row for the first row where preceding sibling is null -->
            <xsl:when test="row = 1">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @lalengua thanks for the quick answer.  Your solution does the same as mine except adds an 'H' in front of all row values.  I need to null out certain values in header row and the regular rows per the sample output.

Comment: It does not. It applies a template to specific node (row), you'll then should create a rule for each type of node and apply changes only to header part. Do you think that aproach could do the trick?

Comment: Yes, I meant it applies the template to specific node (row).  I tried to make such a rule for each node and apply the changes in the header part but it applies the rules to all <fruit> nodes, not just the header.  Even your example puts the 'H' in all <row> nodes, not just the ones in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 this is

```
<xsl:template match="fruits">
  <fruits>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="fruit" group-adjacent="type">
      <xsl:copy>
        <row>H<xsl:value-of select="row"/></row>
        <type><xsl:value-of select="type"/></type>
        <name/>
        <color/>
        <country><xsl:value-of select="country"/></country>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </fruits>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'll edit the answer accordingly-**

***XSLT script code:***

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fruit">
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="child::type"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1][type != $type] or (count(preceding-sibling::fruit) = 0)">
                <fruit>
                    <row>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('H', row)"/>
                    </row>
                    <type> <xsl:value-of select="type"/></type>
                    <name> </name>
                    <color> </color>
                    <country> <xsl:value-of select="country"/> </country>
                </fruit>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***Below output generated by XSLT script:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fruits>
    <fruit>
      <row>H1</row>
      <type> Apple </type>
      <name/>
      <color/>
      <country> US </country>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>

        <row>1</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Gala </name>
        <color> Red </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>

        <row>2</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Fuji </name>
        <color> Red </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>

        <row>3</row>
        <type> Apple </type>
        <name> Golden Delcious </name>
        <color> Yellow </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
      <row>H4</row>
      <type> Orange </type>
      <name/>
      <color/>
      <country> US </country>
   </fruit>
   <fruit>

        <row>4</row>
        <type> Orange </type>
        <name> Clementine </name>
        <color> Orange </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <row>5</row>
        <type> Orange </type>
        <name> Sunburst </name>
        <color> Orange </color>
        <country> US </country>
    </fruit>
</fruits>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Here is another approach to handle your question in XSLT version 2.0:***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fruits">
        <fruits>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="fruit" group-by="type">
                <fruit>
                    <row>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('H', current-group()[1]//row)"></xsl:value-of>
                    </row>
                    <type> <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]//type"/></type>
                    <name> </name>
                    <color> </color>
                    <country> <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]//country"/> </country>
                </fruit>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>                
            </xsl:for-each-group>
       </fruits>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```